# Suitescript 2.0: insert line into sublist if current line meets criteria

Tags: suitescript2.0

The record is a invoice or sales order.

An item and a quantity for the item is entered on the standard Netsuite sublist 'Item'.

If the item is on back order (which you can tell once the quantity is entered and you tab out of the line), then I want the original line's quantity to be adjusted so that it equals quantity available and the newly inserted line to be for the quantity on back order.

Is possible?

I am thinking it would be a client script to insert additional lines on the sublist.

I'm not sure if a script has the functionality to adjust the original line though since it hasn't been committed to the database yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant but why not just do it on "validate line" instead. Meaning let them add the line and right after the user clicks add adjust the quantity if need be and create the new line with the remaining backordered quantity?

Comment: Thanks Nadav. I adjusted the user preferences in Netsuite (I will have to check which settings so I can update this) so that if the item is on back order it didn't appear on the invoice at all